# SQLITE - Delete rows with self join?

Tags: sqlite, syntax

I am trying to delete all rows in a simple table that have a duplicate value except for the duplicate with the highest id.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Expression] (
                      [ID] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                      [Value] VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL
                      )
```

Attempted Queries:

```
DELETE Expression 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Expression Exp2 
    WHERE Expression.Value=Exp2.Value 
        AND Expression.Id < Exp2.Id)
```

fails with

> "SQL logic error or missing database near "Expression":syntax error"

```
DELETE Exp1 
FROM Expression Exp1 
  INNER JOIN Expression Exp2 
    ON Exp1.Value=Exp2.Value AND Exp1.Id < Exp2.Id
```

fails with

> "SQL logic error or missing database near "Exp1":syntax error"

What syntax do I need to use?

Comment: How can you have a duplicate data if your column has Primary key? First check the nature of the column.

Comment: The data in the [Value] column is duplicated, not the data in the entire row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the **`FROM`**.

[DELETE command](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)

```
DELETE FROM Expression 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Expression Exp2 
    WHERE Expression.Value=Exp2.Value 
    AND Expression.Id < Exp2.Id
);
```

Comment: Exceedingly close, and got me to the answer which was: DELETE FROM Expression Exp1
                        WHERE EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1 
                            FROM Expression Exp2 
                            WHERE Exp1.Value=Exp2.Value 
                            AND Exp1.Id < Exp2.Id)

Comment: Fun fact: SQLite doesn't allow aliases in delete statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with many ways:

1) **USING CTE:**

```
    WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value) as RowNum
    FROM Expression
     )
  DELETE 
   FROM CTE 
    WHERE ROWNum >1
```

2) USING Temp tables: Same concept

Answer (score 1):

DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1 INNER JOIN contacts t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.email = t2.email;

Comment: this will help to delete the duplicated rows data